# mysql: ask for password interactively when using docker exec

Tags: mysql, docker

Usually you would run the MySQL client to import an SQL file like this:

```
mysql -uexample_user -p example_database < filename.sql
```

It will then ask for the password and after the correct password was provided it will execute the SQL statements in `filename.sql`. This interactive password prompt reduces the risk of the password ending up in the shell history.

When MySQL is running inside a Docker container one could assume that you could do the same using this command:

```
docker exec container_name mysql -uexample_user -p example_database < filename.sql
```

But this is not the case. MySQL will not ask for a password when using this command.

What is the correct `docker` command to allow MySQL to ask for the password?

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing, it seems doing it this way is not possible.

Generally, you can use the argument [`-it`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#options) to start an interactive terminal with a pseudo-tty to get the password prompt from `mysql`, but this argument combination does not allow you to direct files into the command.

To use directed files you need to omit the `-t` argument and only use `-i`. Of course in that case you need to specify the password directly in the command. If you don't want the password to be visible or logged you can use a variable to "hide" it.

```bash
docker exec -i container_name mysql -uexample_user \
  -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" example_database < filename.sql
```

This is also the suggested way by the official [MySQL Docker image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) (see the section *Restoring data from dump files* at the end.

Comment: I'm getting an error message: the input device is not a TTY

Comment: When running the command in a regular shell this should work. I regularly use it exactly like that. If you are running the command differently you should mention that in your question.

Comment: I did some testing, seems like I have to correct myself. I guess I mixed up some commands. See the updated answer.

Comment: Good catch on the official docs. +1 now

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not familiar with docker, but ...)

The conventional way of getting a password into mysql without it being on the command-line is by using an additional Options File containing the password and referencing this file when invoking mysql:

```
$ docker exec container_name \
cat /home/fred/pwd.cnf

[client]
username=example_user
password=MySqlPassword

$ docker exec container_name \
   mysql --defaults-file=/home/fred/pwd.cnf example_database < filename.sql
```

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html

I'm *assuming* you can do something like this because the SQL file you're reading in must also be "within" the container.

Comment: Good idea. Just copy the file with `docker cp pwd.cnf container_name:/pwd.cnf` in the container (or mount it as a volume if you use it regularly).

Comment: And you still need the `-i` argument for `docker exec`, otherwise the `< filename.sql` won't work.